# lightning:recordForm is skipping few fields defined in fields attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

**LightningRecordFormExample.cmp:** (Api version: 45.0)

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="fieldsList" type="List" default="[Name,Phone,Industry]" />

    <lightning:card title="Edit Account" iconName="standard:account">
        <lightning:recordForm   recordId="0013700000Y1ABaAAN"
                                objectApiName="Account"
                                mode="view"
                                columns="2"
                                fields="{!v.fieldsList}"
                                onload="{!c.handleOnLoad}" />           
    </lightning:card>

</aura:component>
```

I dropped this component on Account page layout above the standard Record Detail component.We can see that standard record detail component displays Name and Industry fields but the custom component I created with `lightning:recordForm` is not showing.

[image]

Comment: if you add a layouttype does it change anything (i know its supposed to be optional)?

Comment: @glls adding `layoutType = "Full"` showing all fields including `Name` and `Industry` fields.

Comment: thats  odd  =/ , i would have expected them to show up as well initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the below line

`<aura:attribute name="fieldsList" type="List" default="[Name,Phone,Industry]" />`

to

`<aura:attribute name="fieldsList" type="List" default="['Name','Phone','Industry']" />` and it works fine now.